# Sending ajax form after WordPress authorization

Tags: ajax, wordpress

On the site, standard means are authorized.

If you display `<? Php echo get_current_user_id ()?>` On the page, it will output the authorized user (id)

But if through `AJAX`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    data : $formInfo.serialize(),
    cache: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
```

That from the server returns 0, i.e. not authorized. I tried to enable sending cookies, `withCredentials: true`, but it did not work. How to correctly send an AJAX request from an authorized client

On the server, I created my own plug-in for accepting AJAX requests. Already, both authorization and registration work.

```
    register_rest_route('wc/v2', 'users/set-info', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'pl_user_endpoint_set_info',
));


function pl_user_endpoint_set_info($request = null) {
$response = array();
$parameters = $request->get_body_params();

$response['response'] = $parameters;
$response['message'] = get_current_user_id();
$response['cookie'] = $_COOKIE;// for test cookie

return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);

}
```

The plugin is registered on action rest_api_init

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'pl_wp_rest_endpoints');
```

The code is sent to the client from the form, but until the parameters are processed, I would first learn how to do this so that the server understands that the client is authorized.

Response from server:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1FvS.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the compete HTTP request that was sent. In particular the HTTP cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make an AJAX request, `var_dump (wp_get_current_user ())` returns an empty array. Those. there are no users. It turns out that wordpress simply considers such a request unchecked, so it requires additional authentication. Found the solution here [Authentication ajax rest](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/). It is necessary to transfer simply in a script `nonce`

In function.php after connecting the script:

```
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'wpApiSettings', array(
        'root' => esc_url_raw(rest_url()),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
    ));
```

AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: 'POST',
   processData: false,
   data : $formInfo.serialize(),
   beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
   },
....
```